# GET Request Without Key in URL - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a GET endpoint like the following:

```
http://test.com/api/test/1234
```

where 1234 is the value of the key.  The URL only looks for the value of the key and not the key name itself.

I tried using:

```
var params = {'': vehicleId};
```

to set the parameter, but the resulting URL looks like:

```
http://test.com/api/test?=237819
```

How do I hit my API in the above format using Angular's $Resource .get() method?

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you feel it was of help? This would encourage others to help in the community. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource has to be defined as:

```
var Vehicle = $resource('/api/test/:vehicleId', { vehicleId: '@id' });
```

and then the resource can be used as:

```
Vehicle.get({vehicleId: 1234}, function(data) {
    console.log("data", data);
});
```